# How to change Canvas orientation in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

The standard orientation of Canvas in JavaFx like the following:
[image]

But for me it's not convenient way to draw figures. I want to get the following orientation:

[image]

I have achieved that with following code:

```
    canvas.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    canvas.setRotate(180);
```

Unfortunately, there is a small drawback with such a way, when I try to draw text on canvas it looks rotated on 180 :

[image]

Does anyone know how to set Canvas' orientation in a proper way ?

Comment: A 180° rotation does not result in this effect.A rotation by 180° would move the text to the bottom right and leave the direction of the line unmodified.A transformation that would result in this effect is scaling the image in y direction by -1.Note that the y-axis pointing down ***is the standard image coordinate system*** and there's nothing you could do about it.The only thing you could do would be to apply transforms and every transform that mirrors the axis would necessarily mirror the text too.You could transform the coordinates using a pretty simple calculation though:`yNew=height-yOld`

Comment: When drawing things that are supposed to be mirrored like in your second graphic, you can use a function to transform the Y coordinates accordingly: `int yMirroed = height - y - 1`

Comment: @Marv Fabians formula is the right one. We are not talking about integer pixel values here.